# JavaFX : how to close stage from annother controller

Tags: javafx

i'm developing a JavaFX management application, I am in a situation where I need to succeed serval windows (stages) to complete a process, to ensure that the user can go back at any time without losing information (input fields). I don't close the current stage. Good , now i can go back without losing information
, but I want to know how  can I close all the intermediate stages at the end of process ? when all is done.

More simply i want to know how can i hide or close a stage from annother controller , not its own controller.  or completly another solution to make what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//let,s say this is the method that opens a new scene of AccessControl.FXML, inside FXMLDocumentController.java as a controller.

 public void ShowAccessControlWindow() {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("AccessControl.fxml"));
            stageaccessControl = new Stage();
            stageaccessControl.getIcons().add(new Image(SdaPro.class.getResourceAsStream("/images/hamlog.png")));
            stageaccessControl.setResizable(false);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            stageaccessControl.setScene(scene);
            stageaccessControl.setTitle("TRECLERK BOOKS");
            stageaccessControl.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL); 
            stageaccessControl.show();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    } 

Then to access the parent stage in FXMLDocumentController, it should be a static and to close it in the AccessController or the new controller, 
This is the way ==  FXMLDocumentController.stageTansaction.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of solutions you can use in these cases where you need to access a field from an external controller, which seems to be the issue as far as I understood.

1) You pass a reference to the field to into the necessary controller and the rest is straight forward.

2) If you are worried about the privacy of your stage then you can set up a callback, which could be as simple as an instance of `Runnable`. So whenever necessary you just call its `run()`, which is implemented in your other controller and hides the stage

3) If you want no direct communication whatsoever, make a global/scoped event system. The idea is for one controller to do something like `GlobalEventSystem.fireEvent(Event.STAGE_CLOSE, some reference id to find the stage)` and for the other to listen to such event, when it occurs - check the id, if all good, close the stage, else just ignore the event.

Mainly depends on your app infrastructure, but each of them should be easy to integrate.